# Displaying rows with count 0 with mysql group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables in MySql
Company : (cname,city)
works : (ename,cname,salary)

I want to display number of employees working for every company,
even if that number is zero.

for e.g.
for

```
Company : 
Microsoft Bangalore
IBM       NY

works : 
emp1 Microsoft 10000
emp2 Microsoft 90000
```

output should be :

```
Microsoft 2
IBM 0
```

But the following query and other similar queries print only
those companies which have at least one employee :

```
Select count(*) from works natural join company group by company.cname
```

If I use outer join, then the companies with zero employees will still show
up in one row, so that option is out as well.

How to do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Classic case for a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  c.cname,
  COUNT(w.ename) wcount 
FROM
  company c
  LEFT JOIN works w ON c.cname = w.cname
GROUP BY
  c.cname
```

Comment: P.S.: You should dump NATURAL JOINs. They seem to be handy, but they are not really useful, IMHO. They water down your expressive capabilities and they make implications on how to design your database (column naming), which is a big WTF for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select company.cname, count(work.id) from company left join work on ....=.... group by company.cname
```

where you fill out the "...." parts, and change the work.id to you name

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do so with subquery, here is a sample from my case:

```
select count(`order_id`) as cnt
from (
    select `order_id` from `room_bookings`
    where `room_id` = 3 and `day_id` = 20180201 
    group by `order_id`
) as b;
```