# count(*) Does not return 0 when using group by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have the following query

```
SELECT info, count(*) as info_cnt 
FROM T
WHERE uid = 1 and info IN ('a', 'b','c', 'd')
GROUP BY info
```

It returns

```
+----------+--------+
| info_cnt | info   |
+----------+--------+
|      334 | a      |
|        2 | b      | 
|     1400 | d      |
+----------+--------+
```

How can I write the query so that it returns the count of `c` as `0`.

Comment: It's technically not possible to get that result set from the above query.

Comment: Posible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743456/displaying-rows-with-count-0-with-mysql-group-by

Comment: I have seen it but there he is joining with a different table in the query

Comment: Where is that `uid` come from ? :)

Comment: database won't produce counts for records that don't exist. if there's no `c` values, then you get no `c` counts.

Comment: its one more field in that table @bonCodigo

Comment: you can do it, but you need a table with all four values in it

Comment: @MarcB I was expecting is there a way that it shows 0 if count doesnt exist

Comment: sure, but you'd need a table that contains a/b/c/d to join against.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE info_values (v CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO info_values VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d');
```

And then do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT v, count(uid) as info_cnt 
FROM info_values
LEFT JOIN T ON uid = 1 AND T.info = info_values.v
GROUP BY v
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return zero with the way you have your query written.  If you had the `info` values in a table you could join on them or you can use a subquery similar to this:

```
SELECT c.info, count(t1.info) as info_cnt 
FROM 
(
  select 'a' info
  union all
  select 'b'
  union all
  select 'c'
  union all
  select 'd'
) c
left join T t1
  on c.info = t1.info
  and t1.info IN ('a', 'b','c', 'd')
where uid = 1
GROUP BY c.info
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2675/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39680/1)

```
select distinct t.info, coalesce(a.cnt,0) counts
from T
left join 
(select info, count(*) as cnt
 from T where
 uid = 1
 and info in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
group by info)a
 on t.info = a.info
 group by t.info
;

| INFO | COUNTS |
-----------------
|    a |      2 |
|    b |      1 |
|    c |      0 |
|    d |      3 |
```

Comment: This assumes that you have `c` in the table.. =)