# Hibernate HqlL: Count and Group By including zero?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have 2 tables: Claim and Type_Claim. Claim has an external key on Type_Claim. On Hibernate the Bean that represents Claim table has TypeClaim as an attribute.

```
  Claim

 ID    TYPE
 1      2
 2      2
 3      4
 4      1

  Type_Claim

 ID    Description
 1     "Hello"
 2     "Hi"
 3     "House"
 4     "Welcome"
 5     "Bye"
```

Now i made this query:

```
SELECT tc.description, COUNT(*) 
FROM Claim claim"
LEFT OUTER JOIN claim.typeClaim tc  
GROUP BY tc.description ";
```

I want to obtain this:

```
Description  Count
  "Hello"     1
  "Hi"        2
  "House"     0
  "Welcome"   1
  "Bye"       0
```

But i obtain this:

```
Description  Count
  "Hello"     1
  "Hi"        2
  "Welcome"   1
```

How can i include the 0 results on the query? I tried with RIGHT JOIN but i got same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying rows with count 0 with mysql group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743456/displaying-rows-with-count-0-with-mysql-group-by)

Comment: Should work with a right join. Can you post the SQL generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tc.description, count(cl.type)
FROM type_claim tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN claim cl ON
cl.type = tc.id
GROUP BY tc.description
```

It worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Yes, yesterday i found solution and i made an identhical query but thx however ^^

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate function count() will not count NULL values and thus you'll get a zero.

You must use LEFT JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN

If you want to learn more about outer joins, here is a nice tutorial: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Using_Null

Comment: If you continue to have doubts see this: [How to display 0 in conditional](http://lichao.net/eblog/how-to-display-0-in-conditional-group-by-report-in-count-sql-query-200808164.html)